# Как интегрировать PhpStorm Task с Bitbucket Issues

Tags: phpstorm, bitbucket, task, jira

Подскажите как интегрировать в PhpStorm 10 в задачи Task задачи из Bitbucket Issues

`Tools -> Task & Contexts -> Configure Servers` далее что нужно выбрать.

Спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переходим `Tools > Tasks & Content > Configure servers`

Добавляем сервер тип: `Generic`

**Вкладка: General**

Server URL: `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/*Ваш_Логин*/*Репозиторий*`

Username: Ваш логин

Password: Пароль

Ставим галочку на: `Use HTTP authentication`

**Вкладка: Commit message**

Вводим `{summary} #{id}` - для удобства, что бы в коммитах была сылка на задачу в системе bitbucket

**Вкладка: Server Configuration**

Tasks List URL: `{serverUrl}/issues?status=new&status=open`

Single Task URL: `{serverUrl}/issues/{id}`

Response Type : `JSON`

и далее нижний блок заполняем как на скриншоте [(скриншот)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4wsJ.png)